# The loop does not show users

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, loop, list-authors

I'm trying to show all post made ​​by the author.

Code author.php

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if( get_post_type() == 'post' ) {?>

<?php } if( get_post_type() == 'post-type' ) {?>

<?php } else; endwhile;?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But just shows the post_type "post".

Comment: Is the file name `authors.php` (note *plural*) or `author.php` (note *singular*)?

Comment: oh sorry is author.php

Comment: The `author.php` template file by default only shows posts of the `post` post-type. What have you done to filter the main query to display posts of other post-types?

Comment: Have a look at `pre_get_posts` and `is_author()`, and see if you can come up with a starting point.

Comment: ok i found a sulution with `pre_get_posts`. Thanks

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer for the benefit of future users of this site. Cheers. :)

Comment: Your question should not depend on a third party service. Please add your relevant code inline here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this code to the file `functions.php`.

```
function custom_post_author_archive($query) {
    if ($query->is_author)
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post-type', 'post') );
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_author_archive' );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_author_archive');
```